# Java Redis (jedis) transaction and Sorted Set

Tags: java, transactions, redis, jedis

I am new to Redis and I am experimenting with Redis transactions and I want to use Redis transactions in the following scenario. Need to know if it is feasible to do this:

1. Start Transaction.
2. Read top 10 elements from sorted set.
3. A 'for loop' for each of the elements to do something.
4. Execute.

I tried the following code but it isn't working as I am doing a `<Response>.get()` before executing the transaction.

```
final Transaction tx = jedis.multi();
final Response<Set<Tuple>> tuples = tx.zrangeByScoreWithScores("randomKey", 0d, 100, 0, 10);
for (final Tuple tuple : tuples.get()) {
    jedis.incr(tuple);
}
tx.exec(); //In a hope that get and sets happen in a single transaction.
```

Is there a way to go around this?

Comment: Have you looked at doing it redis-site with Lua and EXEC?

Comment: Yes, that's the hack I am trying right now. Was hoping to get something using Pipelining and Transactions.

Comment: Since you need the data to be able to iterate over it you'll either have to do it in two stages client side, or use Lua server side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Redisson](https://redisson.org) instead. Use Lock object instead of transaction. Example for your case:

```
RLock lock = redisson.getLock("myLock");
lock.lock();
try {
    Collection<ScoredEntry<V>> entries = redisson.getScoredSortedSet("randomKey").entryRange(true, 0, true, 100, 0, 10);
    for (final ScoredEntry<V> entry : entries) {
       redisson.getAtomicLong(entry.getValue()).incrementAndGet();
    }
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```